# The meaning of "it will be remembered" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a CS Lewis's essay we read :

> His fourth point, **it will be remembered**, was that science had undermined not only what he regards as the mythological accretions of religion, but also what he regards as its essence.

I didn't get the meaning of "it will be remembered" in this context, can someone explain.

Comment: Take care to use capital letters at the start of sentences!

Answer (score 1):

C.S Lewis could have written:

> His fourth point, *you remember*, was ...

Lewis is reminding the reader of the fourth point that some other author had made. Presumably, Lewis had already told the reader about the other author's points. Lewis had listed the other author's points.  Now he is rebutting each point.  He reminds the reader of the fourth point.

He could write "you remember" or "you will remember", but in the fairly formal style that Lewis is using he uses a passive phrase "it will be remembered". This avoids directly addressing the reader with "you".

But this phrase could be omitted entirely without changing the main meaning of the paragraph.

> His fourth point was that science had...

Answer (score 0):

At the start of his May 1946 paper, "Religion without dogma?",  Lewis lists four points made by Professor HH price in an October 1944 paper, "The Grounds of Modern Agnosticism". This paper was first read aloud to the Oxford Socratic Club. Such insertions are common in formal speeches, where reference is being made to something previously mentioned, or which can be presumed to be known to the listener. Here, he refers to the fourth point, which, he says "will be remembered [by the reader or listener, who saw or heard it earlier]".